# Acts_as_commentable not getting commentable_id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So I've been stuck at this for an hour or so now. The problem I am having is not getting the "Tour.id". However if I do:

```
commentable = Tour.find(1)
comment = commentable.comments.create
```

it saves with the right commentable_id and commentable_type.

Here's how things are looking:

**show.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for [@tour, @comment] do |f| %>
 <%= f.text_area :comment %>
<% end %>
```

**tours_controller.rb**

```
@tour = Tour.find(params[:id])
@comment = @tour.comments.new
```

**comments_controller.rb**

```
@commentable = @tour
@comment = @commentable.comments.create
```

**routes.rb**

```
resources :tours do
 resources :comments
 member do
  put :submitreview
 end 
end
```

results in:
    NoMethodError in CommentsController#create
    undefined method `comments' for nil:NilClass

Request

Parameters:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
"authenticity_token"=>"mxHD+yj6PKG4gCrYuGrwKEKWHOofCaoE4G7bAoEs6J4=",
"comment"=>{"comment"=>"okokok"},
"commit"=>"Create Comment",
"tour_id"=>"1"}
```

What am I doing wrong here?!

Comment: as per error in your comments_controller `@tour` is nil. Can you check that?

Comment: @shivam if I change commentable = Tour.find(params[:id]) it returns: undefined method `find' for nil:NilClass, however thhe tour_id is still present in the parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the action in your comments controller, you aren't assigning `@tour` any value thus it's nil. And then your calling `comments` on it in the next line. Which is why you're getting that error.

Comment: by changing the @tour to Tour.find(params[:tour_id]) I was able to get it working properly. Any idea on how I can get the user_id?

Comment: Where is the user_id? Please mention the relationship and show us the routes. Also tell where do you want the user_id? :)